# PHP File Operations list

Tags: php, file-io

I'm looking for a list of each file operation. I Googled on http://www.google.se/search?q=Php+File+Operations, but didn't found anything.

Do you know a where I could find a list of PHP file operations?

```
$file = fopen("words.txt","**r**"); the r is once File Operation
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question needs clarifying, but try the [PHP Filesystem Functions](https://www.php.net/ref.filesystem) section in the PHP manual.  (All I did was search for 'PHP file functions' on Google).

If what you're looking for is the **file open *modes*** (such as "r", etc.), then you need to look at [the fopen() page](https://www.php.net/fopen) in the manual (there's a table just down the page).

Answer (score 0):

Here they have the list of all file functions on the left and within the body of that document they have all the modes you can use within fopen

[Link](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

Is http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing file work within php, I highly recommend looking at the SPL libraries, as they're a much nicer API, and OO to boot.

General SPL info can be found here: http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/
And a decent tutorial: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html